# Uncaught TypeError: d3.bullet is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bullet-chart

Hi guys i have a problem creating a simple d3 chart for a javascript web project. This code is kind of created like in a tutorial so i don't really know why i get the error: 
 Uncaught TypeError: d3.bullet is not a function 
as i installed d3 and am also linking the newest d3 version in the first script. I haven't seen this error before when googling or searching it on stackoverflow.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bullet.js"></script>
 <script>
  var margin = {top: 5, right: 40, bottom:20 , left:120},
  width = 800-margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 50-margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var chart = d3.bullet()
          .width(width)
          .height(height);

  d3.json("data/jsonFakeDaten.json", function(error, data) {
    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
          .data(data)
        .enter().appennd("svg")
          .attr("class","bullet")
          .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
          .call(chart);


    var title = svg.append("g")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + height / 2 + ")");

    title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

    title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "subtitle")
      .attr("dy", "lem")
      .text(function (d) { return d.subtitle; });

    d3.selectAll("button").on("click", function() {
      svg.datum(randomize).call(chart.duration(1000));
    });

  });

  function randomize(d) {
    if(!d.randomizer) d.randomizer = randomizer(d);
    d.markers = d.markers.map(d.randomizer);
    d.measures = d.measures.map(d.randomizer);
    return d;
  }

  function randomizer(d) {
    var k = d3.max(d.ranges) * .2;
    return function(d) {
      return Math.max(0,d + k * (Math.random() - .5));
    };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you put `bullet.js` in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I've noticed is that you have a typo here:

```
    .enter().appennd("svg")
```

That could be causing some errors for you, also if you're using the bullet.js from Bostock's bl.ocks.org example, then you should be using d3.v3 not v4 because they're not compatible.

Comment: Hi! And do you know if the correct way to create bullet chart in d3 v4 then?

Comment: npm install d3v4-bullet should do it